# Install Ubuntu to USB 3.0 external drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive

Yes I am trying to install Ubuntu to a USB external hard drive.  I partition the drive and I put down install grub to the external hard drive so I did change this but for some reason it keeps installing grub to the internal drive.  I'm trying to do this with 16.10 and I'm getting a little frustrated.  I've tried to install it like three or four times and I keep telling it to install grub to the external drive but for whatever reason it wont do it.  Can Ubuntu not be installed to a USB external drive?

This is an external hard drive not a small USB pin drive.  Just to make this clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator)

Comment: **Just disconnect the internal drive while you install Ubuntu.**

Comment: @M.Becerra - Nah, I don't think this is a dupe of that.

Answer (score 2):

It works like that in UEFI mode. It 'wants' to use the existing EFI partition in the first drive (usually the internal drive /dev/sda).

But if you ***unplug or disconnect the internal drive*** (and have no extra drive connected), the installer will be happy(?) to install grub into your target drive, the USB external hard drive. That is how I do it.

Comment: Yes that does make since it's just odd I've had no problem install Fedora 25 to an external drive.  But I know each version of Linux is different so I will try and open up my laptop and disconnect the internal drive.  Thank you for the advice it really helped a lot.

Comment: You are welcome and good luck :-)