# Linux Ubuntu on two hard drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have Windows 10 on SSD and now I replaced dvd with second HDD. Now I want to install Ubuntu into the second HDD without touching the first HDD. I want to set things up so that if I change the boot order I can switch who loading.

My laptop is acer with UEFI, and when I finish the installation of Ubuntu, the HDD with Ubuntu does not appear in the UEFI menu. I set up the partitions with efi fat32, ext4 with mount point `/` and swap area.

Comment: UEFI will always read the ESP (EFI partition) from the first drive only, no need to create another in the other drive. Make sure you're booting the Ubuntu installer in UEFI mode and install as usual but creating/selecting the partitions for Ubuntu in the second drive; the installer will install the boot files for Ubuntu in sda's ESP.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to solve this problem.

1. Use the internal drive's EFI partition like Zanna suggests. See the following link for more details,

   [Install Ubuntu on Second Hard Drive whilst Leaving Unallocated Space for Use by Other Operating Systems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863882/install-ubuntu-on-second-hard-drive-whilst-leaving-unallocated-space-for-use-by/863894#863894)
2. Do not touch the internal drive

   2a. Do not touch the internal drive. Instead make an installed system that can manage to boot and run on its own. See the following link for more details, with the standard installer and with the internal drive disconnected,

   [Install Ubuntu to USB 3.0 external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861420/install-ubuntu-to-usb-3-0-external-drive/861424#861424)

   2b. There is a shortcut to an installed Ubuntu or Ubuntu family system, that boots in both UEFI and BIOS mode. It was created from the Ubuntu Server iso file and is rather portable between computers. See this link for more details, how to install this system from a compressed image file,

   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS

   This method will clone the compressed image file, which is straight-forward with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), and you need not disconnect the internal drive, only select the correct target drive, and mkusb helps to do that.